# i am curious about the cause of python error

Tags: python, list

```
d=[]
for i in range(1,20):
    d=list(map(int, input().split()))

n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    x,y=map(int,input().split())
    for j in range(1,20):
        if d[j][y] == 0:
            d[j][y] =1
        else :
            d[j][y] ==0
    for j in range(1,20):
        if d[x][j]==0:
             d[x][j]=1
             
        else :
            d[x][j]=0


for i in range(1,20):
    print(x, end=' ')
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/e.py", line 9, in <module>
    if d[j][y] == 0:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscribable
```

I am curious about the cause of the error

Comment: Since `d` is a list of numbers, what do you intend to do with `d[j][y] == 0`? What would you access by indexing a number?

Comment: You seem to expect `d` to be a list of lists of ints, but it isn't - it's just a list of ints, the ones from the 20th line of input (since you overwrote all the previous lines in the first loop).  You need to append each line to `d`, rather than replace it completely.

Comment: @jasonharper, it's actually list of one element (int), because they keep overwriting it inside the loop on line 3

Comment: Actually, `d` has only one element thus, the error I get from running your code is `IndexError: list index out of range` on line 10 `if d[j][y] == 0`, because first value of `j` is 1 and there is only 1 element at. index 0

Answer (score 1):

You fill your variable `d` with data with the following code:

```
d=list(map(int, input().split()))
```

This creates a `list` of `int` elements.

`d[2]` will give you the third element of this list, namely an `int`. Adding a second index, e.g. `d[2][1]` will try to get element `1` of an `int` value. This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in provided code:

1. This code seems to do not what you want, on every iteration list is overwritten, so if you want to have matrix like [[1,2,3],[5,6,7], ...] you need to use append method of a list
   d=[]
   for i in range(1,20):
   d=list(map(int, input().split())) instead of this you need to use:
   for i in range(1,20):
   d.append(list(map(int, input().split(","))))
2. The second issue about what you are asking occurs because of first one, you are trying to access by index from int value, I don't know what input values you used, but seems like your list looks like [n], where n is random integer you inputed, therefore after first operation d[n] you got integer value and second getting value from integer by index d[n][m] can not be made

I would recommend to use prints or debuger for better understanding